# QNetworkReply error signal cant emits continuously

Tags: c++, qt, qnetworkaccessmanager, qnetworkreply

I need to get xml information from a web page and I can.

I do it with a timer for getting information continuously.

My problem is, I couldnt catch the error signals continuosly. I only catch it once.

I tried examples on QT help page, I read a lot but there is no succes.

Here are my codes;

***mainwindow.h***

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTimer>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QNetworkReply *reply;
    QNetworkRequest request;
    QNetworkAccessManager *manager;
    QTimer *timer;

private slots:
    void replyFinished(QNetworkReply*);
    void updateDB();
    void slotError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError);
    void slotSslErrors(QList<QSslError>);
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

***mainwindow.cpp***

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);

    request.setUrl(QUrl("https://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml"));

    // Get response
    updateDB();

    // Signals for xml
    connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
    connect(reply, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)),this, SLOT(slotError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)));
    connect(reply, SIGNAL(sslErrors(QList<QSslError>)),this, SLOT(slotSslErrors(QList<QSslError>)));

    // Update timer
    timer = new QTimer(this);
    timer->start(2000);
    connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(updateDB()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::replyFinished(QNetworkReply *)
{
    qDebug() << reply->readAll();
    reply->deleteLater();
}

void MainWindow::updateDB()
{
    reply = manager->get(request);
}

void MainWindow::slotError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)
{
    qDebug() << "slotError";
    reply->deleteLater();
}

void MainWindow::slotSslErrors(QList<QSslError>)
{
    qDebug() << "slotSslErrors";
    reply->deleteLater();
}
```

Edit: I'm using QT 5.13.1 and I have added QT += network on .pro file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your UpdateDB, you create a new reply:

```
reply = manager->get(request);
```

But you never connect its signals.

The very first one gets its signals connected in the constructor, which is why it works for the first one.

The fix is easy: move your signal connection for the `reply` from the constructor to the UpdateDB function, so this is done for every new reply object you create:

```
reply = manager->get(request);
connect(reply, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)),this, SLOT(slotError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)));
connect(reply, SIGNAL(sslErrors(QList<QSslError>)),this, SLOT(slotSslErrors(QList<QSslError>)));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @spectras .I understood my mistake but your suggestion will make a new signal creation everytime I call updateDB, right ? So after a while there will be lots of signals and requests....

Comment: A signal is just a function of your class, nothing is created when you connect it. You are just... connecting the signal to the slot. (internally, that connection does imply some book records, but Qt manages it for you)